# how to use .so files in GoogleTV projects

Tags: google-tv

I have created a GoogleTV project(**GoogleTV AddOn API 12**).Here, I need to use a third-party player for implementing Http Live streaming.Now, when I ran the code, It is giving me "UnSatisfiedLinkError" which is thrown when the .so files are not found(specifically for this project).Now, I did extract the APK and found that the .so files are present at lib/armeabi folder and not lib folder.
I have placed all the jar files in the libs folder and pasted all the .so files in armeabi folder(which is placed inside libs folder).**strong text**

Can someone suggest any pointer on this?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

NDK / .so files are not yet available for Google TV.

Comment: Hi Les,Can I compile the GoogleTv code on Android 2.2 and run the apk on googleTv.Actually, I need a compile-time environment for my code to be 2.2 even If I am creating any GoogleTV project.Please provide some pointer on this, If it is possible.Also, If I am running my App on GoogleTV, Is it possible to use any jar files and .so files for communication between the activities.   Thanks!!

Comment: As both Krispy and I mentioned - there isn't an NDK at this point, so you can't use .so files.

Comment: Yes, It is correct.But, I wanted to know if there is any compile-time dependancy on the .apk file.As per my colleague, He has deployed an apk with API 8 on googleTv and it ran well on GoogleTV.The application was using .so files to communicate while playing an HLS video.Please provide your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

A few things. 
There is no NDK support on Google TV at this time. You will not be able to use any code/libs that use NDK if you are writing a Google TV application. Also, you should target API 13 for your Google TV project.